# STM32f103 DMA with PWM repeating values

Tags: pwm, stm32f10x, dma, ws2812b

I have a Blue Pill (STM32F103) and connected to it a ws2812b led strip. I am trying to send data to the led strip via PWM over the TIM2 peripheral (Pin A0). To change the duty cycle of the TIM2 PWM I use a DMA channel. This works perfectly at lower speeds (eg 100khz) but as soon as I get near to the required 800khz of the leds the MCU seems to send some pulses twice, this would make sense if I overload the bus, but from what I have gotten out of the datasheet it should be able to handle 800 kbyte/s.

What makes the entire thing more complicated, is that I am trying to write this in Rust and there is no code I could compare mine too. I will try to post the relevant parts of the code and explain it as good as I can.

Main Code:

```
// setup pwm
let mut pwm = p.TIM2
    .pwm(
        c1,
        &mut afio.mapr,
        800.khz(),
        clocks,
        &mut rcc.apb1,
    );

let max = pwm.get_max_duty();

let one_duty = (max * 16 / 25) as u8;


let buf = singleton!(: [u8; 25] = [one_duty, one_duty, one_duty, one_duty, one_duty, one_duty, one_duty, one_duty, one_duty, one_duty, one_duty, one_duty, one_duty, one_duty, one_duty, one_duty, one_duty, one_duty, one_duty, one_duty, one_duty, one_duty, one_duty, one_duty, 0]).unwrap();

// set duty to zero
pwm.set_duty(0);
// enable pwm output
pwm.enable();
// enable the dma and wait for it to finish
pwm.write_all(channels.5, buf).wait();
```

WriteAll function code:

```
pub fn write_all<A, B>(
    self,
    mut chan: $c1_chan,
    buffer: B,
    ) -> Transfer<R, B, $c1_chan, Self>
where
    A: Unsize<[u8]>,
    B: Static<A>,
{
    {
        unsafe { (*$TIMX::ptr()).dier.modify(|_, w| {
            w   .tde().set_bit()
                .cc1de().set_bit()
        }); }

        let buffer: &[u8] = buffer.borrow();
        chan.cmar().write(|w| unsafe {
            w.ma().bits(buffer.as_ptr() as usize as u32)
        });
        chan.cndtr().write(|w| unsafe{
            w.ndt().bits(u16(buffer.len()).unwrap())
        });
        chan.cpar().write(|w| unsafe {
            w.pa().bits(&(*$TIMX::ptr()).ccr1 as *const _ as usize as u32)
        });

        atomic::compiler_fence(Ordering::SeqCst);

        chan.ccr().modify(|_, w| {
            w.mem2mem().clear_bit()
                // priority
                .pl().high()
                // size in memory
                .msize().bit8()
                .psize().bit32()
                .minc().set_bit()
                .pinc().clear_bit()
                .circ().clear_bit()
                .dir().set_bit()
                .teie().set_bit()
                .htie().set_bit()
                .tcie().set_bit()
                // enable
                .en().set_bit()
        });
    }
}
```

My question is: why is DMA not fast enough even though it should be as stated by the documentation?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please clarify the question that you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution while writing this question. I thought I post it anyway since it might help other people. After calling write_all I call wait, which constantly polls the result. This occupied the bus and slowed down the DMA transfer.

Edit: I did not set the right clock multiplier, so the MCU ran at only 8mhz. When running faster, it works great.